# EF 6, adding entity to DbContext creates duplicate entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I have a web application (MVC 5, EntityFramework 6).  It's connected to an SQL database via a DbContext.  I'm having an issue where adding a new entity object creates a duplicate entry in the entity set (but not the DB) and I'm not sure how to stop this from happening.

Controller, whose method is called via an ajax request:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();  //DbContext

    public ActionResult SaveStuff(string customerId, string stuff)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Single(c => c.ID.Equals(customerId));
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(stuff, customer);
        db.Stuffs.Add(stuff);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("MyControl", customer);
    }
}
```

There is a 1-to-many association between Customer and Stuff, and there is a "Stuffs" navigation property in Customer.

Stuff includes fields that are *int*, *string*, and *DateTime*.

The controller method returns a PartialView which is used by JavaScript to refresh the contents of a control.

The "MyControl" control does this:

```
var stuffs = Model.Stuffs.OrderByDescending(...);
```

When the control is rendered in this situation, `Model.Stuffs` contains a duplicate entry.  There's an entry with a name of `Stuff` (probably the new object created in the control method) as well as well as an entry with a name of `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Stuff_<uuid>` which is the same exact data (I imagine read from the DB).

This is only a problem when I'm writing into and then reading from an entity set within the same web request.  Other/future web requests that cause a read are fine.  How can I make this work correctly?

Comment: What is the value of `MyDBEntities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` ?

Comment: you are adding new entry.Are you sure there are no existing entry in database for same record ? In that case you may want to edit the same entry

Comment: `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` is definitely enabled, @VDohnal

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the DateTime object is losing precision when it is written into the SQL database (see: [SQL Server DateTime vs .NET DateTime](http://seesharper.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/sql-server-datetime-vs-net-datetime-battle-of-accuracy/)).  When read back from the DB, it has a different value and therefore does not overwrite the existing "stuff" object that still exists locally in db.Stuffs.

A simple solution is to change the DateTime's setter for Stuff to private and add your own pseudo-setter function that has the rounding built into it:

```
public void SetTimestamp(DateTime timestamp)
{
    //Precision in SQL is lower than in .NET, so just round to tenth seconds
    this.Updated = timestamp.AddTicks(- (timestamp.Ticks % (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 10)));
}
```

Using DateTime2 in the SQL database (Server 2008+) is also an option should you need to maintain that level of precision.

Comment: That shouldn't insert a new object, at most it would update the existing row.

Comment: Well, the DateTime is part of the table key so that may have changed the behavior...

Comment: Ahh.. yes, there was no way to know that from your question